# script for clearing exim queue & sending email myself with email & subject in email

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Can anyone tell me what the issue with this script?

```
(printf "To:myemail@mydomain.com\nSubject: Mail queue cleanup for for My-VPS-Linux\n\n" ; /usr/sbin/exim -bp | awk '/^ *[0-9]+[mhd]/{print "/usr/sbin/exim -Mrm " $3}' ) | bash | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@mydomain.com
```

as soon as I run this via SSH I get this error

```
bash: line 1: To:myemail@mydomain.com: command not found
bash: line 2: Subject:: command not found
```

---

All I want to acheive is to clear the exim queue through this script after defining in cronjob. When I run following script

```
/usr/sbin/exim -bp | awk '/^ *[0-9]+[mhd]/{print "/usr/sbin/exim -Mrm " $3}' ) | bash | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@mydomain.com
```

it works pretty fine and send me an email after clearing email queue but it does not post any subject or to email address...

Regards,
Faraz H. Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have put the subshell first, your Subject: and To: print lines are printed before the output of `exim`, and are being processed by `bash`. You should move the subshell later on:

```
/usr/sbin/exim -bp | awk '/^ *[0-9]+[mhd]/{print "/usr/sbin/exim -Mrm " $3}' | (printf "To:myemail@mydomain.com\nSubject: Mail queue cleanup for for My-VPS-Linux\n\n"; bash) | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@mydomain.com
```

This prints your Subject: and To: lines before any other output, but `bash` will not process those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the print output to bash. You need to send the print output to sendmail. Your `)` is in the wrong place. (Assuming the output from that `exim|awk` pipe is the body of the email you get and prepending headers the way you are trying will make `sendmail` do the right thing, etc., etc..)